# What's the best way to dequeue / remove uncooperative scripts and styles?

Tags: performance, wp-enqueue-style

So we've got `wp_dequeue_script`, `wp_dequeue_style` as well as `wp_deregister_style`and `wp_dequeue_script`...

These work well, as long as they've been called correctly in the first place.

Some plugins, such as Woocommerce's "Smart Coupons", for example, call these in a function like so:

```
public function register_plugin_styles() {
global $pagenow;

$is_frontend = ( ! is_admin() ) ? true : false;
$is_valid_post_page = ( ! empty( $pagenow ) && in_array( $pagenow, array( 'edit.php', 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) ) ) ? true : false;
$is_valid_admin_page = ( ! empty( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] == 'woocommerce_smart_coupon_csv_import' ) ? true : false;

if ( $is_frontend || $is_valid_admin_page || $is_valid_post_page ) {
    wp_register_style( 'smart-coupon', untrailingslashit( plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ ) ) . '/assets/css/smart-coupon.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'smart-coupon' );
}

}
```

Which kills our ability to simply add:

```
wp_deregister_style('smart-coupon');
```

So what's the best way to remove these? Specifically, I'd like code for functions.php as opposed to adding yet another plugin.

Comment: How is the code hooked? What is the `add_action()` call look like?

Comment: `add_action( 'init', array(  $this, 'register_plugin_styles' ) );`

Comment: ... enqueued on the wrong hook... big surprise. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I found that this works: `function dequeue_unnecessary_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'smart-coupon' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'smart-coupon' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'dequeue_unnecessary_styles' );` but is that the best way?